# Сортировка вставкой в процессе сортировки слиянием

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка

Идея заключается в том, чтобы реализовать сортировку слиянием, в которой `n/k` подмассивов длиной `k` сортировались вставкой, после чего объединялись обычным слиянием. В наихудшем случае модифицированный алгоритм выполняется за `O(nlog(n/k) + nk)`. Обычный же алгоритм слияния в наихудшем случает дает `O(nlogn)`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как подобрать оптимальное `k`?

Comment: Методом научного тыка. А вообще в java для timsort пороговое значение в 64 элемента установлено. Подозреваю, что оптимальное значение гдет-то рядом, в зависиоти от задачи и языка

Comment: да, да, вы заново изобрели https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort